# Countdown function connected to ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I currently have an PrimeFaces `<p:poll>` ajax poll function that executes every 90 seconds to refresh some data. I've been asked to make this visual and I'm just wondering the quickest/lightest way of doing so?

The way I am thinking is I have two options:

1. Create a PrimeFaces `<p:poll>` that executes every second, reducing a global JavaScript number variable, which when it gets to 0 then executes the ajax to refresh the data, although this could be subsceptible to processing lag?

   or
2. Find/Build some sort of count down timer in jQuery/JS and like above execute when it's finished counting down.

Hopefully somebody has a cleaner/better method.

Comment: `"I've been asked to make this visual"` - What do you mean exactly?

Comment: A visual representation of the poll function. i.e. a countdown timer, which when it reaches 0 it executes an ajax function and updates the web page with the newly retrieved data. The countdown timer is then reset and the process starts again.

Comment: There are [a number of previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=javascript%20countdown%20timer) on SO regarding JavaScript countdown timers. Is there any reason none of those answer your question?

Comment: Because I am not specifically asking how to do it using a Javascript timer. I am asking if the method(s) I suggested were the viable paths to take and which of them is the 'quickest/lightest' in terms of resources. I am dev'ing on a resource heavy platform so I am trying to keep new functions/features as light a poss. I used the search function and there was nothing which was specific to a JSF and/or Primefaces context so I was asking the community if there was a good solution using the above component library's. If not then I will go back to the other Javascript countdown timers you mentioned

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I interpreted your previous comment to mean that you were interested in implementing this with JavaScript. I don't have any experience with JSF, but good luck with your project!

Comment: How can you see the difference between 1 and 2 ? Both are implemented same way for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for this case, it would be better to use `<p:remoteCommand` instead of `<p:poll`.

That way you can code the countdown/display using JQuery and call the remote-command and reset the count to 90 when the count reaches 0.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="fetchData" action="#{...}" update="..."/>
<!-- fetchData here will be a global javascript function. -->
```

[RemoteCommand showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf)

A problem with using `<p:poll` is that the poll's timer and the display timer won't synchronize.